# Indexing the values of string elements from array perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, indexing

I have an array which contains some DNA sequences as strings stored in its elements.
Ex: `print $array[0];` give an output like this: `ACTAG` (#the first position in each sequence).

I have written this code that allows me to analyse the first position for each sequence.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
$infile = @ARGV[0];
$ws= $ARGV[1];
$wsnumber= $ARGV[2];                  

open INFILE, $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!";        # This opens file, but if file isn't there it mentions this will not open

my $sequence = ();  # This sequence variable stores the sequences from the .fasta file
my $line;                             # This reads the input file one-line-at-a-time

while ($line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp $line;

    if ($ws ne "--ws=") {
     print "no flag or invalid flag\n";
     last;
    }
     else {
        if($line =~ /^\s*$/) {         # This finds lines with whitespaces from the beginning to the ending of the sequence. Removes blank line.
        next;

    } elsif($line =~ /^\s*#/) {        # This finds lines with spaces before the hash character. Removes .fasta comment
        next; 
    } elsif($line =~ /^>/) {           # This finds lines with the '>' symbol at beginning of label. Removes .fasta label
        next;
    } else {
        $sequence = $line;

    $sequence =~ s/\s//g;               # Whitespace characters are removed


    @array = split //,$sequence;
    $seqlength = length($sequence);}
}

    $count=0;
foreach ($array[0]){
    if( $array[0] !~ m/A|T|C|G/ ){
        next;
        }
    else {
        $count += 1;
        $suma += $count;

         }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to modify $array[0] for running this code for each position (I'm only manage to do it for a specific postion (in the above example for the first position).

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: **ALWAYS** `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking at one element in your array:

```
foreach ($array[0]){ ... }
```

To iterate over the whole array use:

```
my @array = qw(ATTTCFCGGCTTA);

foreach (@array){
    my @split = split('');
    foreach (@split){
        die "$_ is not a valid character\n" unless /[ATGC]/;
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I think It should works but it isn't working. I print "$_\n" and I think that $_ is storing each postion Of my sequences. I have edited my post and inserted all code. Can you look at it please? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have just observed that my @array doesn't contain one sequence by element. All sequences are in 1 element. SO how can I solve it? Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand well, but is that what you want?

Assuming `@array` contains one sequence by element.

```
foreach my $seq(@array) {
    my @chars = split '', $seq;
    foreach my $char(@char) {
        if ($char =~ /[ATCG]/) {
            # do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm I don't know why it isn't working because I think It should work. Can you look again to my post? I have edited it and inserted all my code. Thank you!

Comment: I have just observed that my @array doesn't contain one sequence by element. All sequences are in 1 element. SO how can I solve it?